# How can I redirect to the same page multiple times with a different query string?

Tags: vb.net, redirect

I have a page that contains a table with a list of data and an icon (on each row) which redirects the user to a new aspx page with a queryString and does some custom logic to then download the file. The user has asked that we make a "download all" button so they don't have to go through and manually click every icon in every row.

My code is close, I feel, but it will hang after the first file is downloaded and will never progress further.

Here is the code I have so far

```
 Protected Sub ibDownloadAll_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) 
      'Get Parameters
      'Run stored procedure to get the query string we're going to use
      'Fill DataSet

       For Each myItem As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Response.Redirect("redirectPage?ID=" &myItem.Item("ID")) 'Gets stuck after here
       Next
 End Sub
```

I realized if I added the second parameter (Indicates whether execution of the
current page should terminate)

```
 Response.Redirect("redirectPage?ID=" &myItem.Item("ID"), False)
```

Then it would make it to the end of the function, running through the loop as expected, but then only outputting/downloading the last file.

Is there something I'm missing or an alternative that can be used to effectively redirect multiple times? Unfortunately with the framework I'm using I'm not able to use Response.Write and put custom scripts in that way, nor can I really change the page that we are redirecting to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect to multiple pages (a redirect close the request) and you also can't send multiple files. Your only option would be to have a request that zip all the files together. You can do this with [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.7.2). You don't need to save the zip on disk, you could just send the memory stream.